# Cumulative Frequency Graph - Mistake in Textbook?

Tags: statistics

Question 2a in this textbook asks for the range of this cumulative frequency graph.  No other data is given, just the graph.  According to the key in the back of the book the answer is 37 cm.  How did they get this answer?  Is it a mistake?  [link to image from textbook with graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DFOj.png)

Comment: Should it be 55? Do they mean interquartile range instead?

Comment: Yes I thought it should be 55...  Wouldn't make sense for IQR either...